# Describe a sine wave of known frequency with only two points

Tags: calculus, statistics, physics

This is my first post on math.stackexchange (sorry if meta people remove the Hello (sometimes we do that over on stackoverflow ;P)!

I have a system wherein I know that the output is a sine wave, with a known frequency.  My objective is to find the approximate (x,y) of the first peak (i.e., find the phase shift of the signal).  An important point is that I do not need to know y, or the amplitude, of this peak.  Essentially, I can poll the system at a given angular shift (represented by x), and receive a y value in return.  I start with zero points, and want to poll the minimum number of x points in order to be able to know where to poll to receive a max y value.

I believe that I can describe the sine wave with only two points, yet I do not know how to calculate this (it's on a motion controller, so I have quite limited functionality).  My thoughts so far:  phase = -sin^-1(y) - wt + 2*pi*n, but I don't know how to easily fit this with two points.

Once I know the fitted sine wave, I will be able to determine which x should yield a max amplitude peak y, and then subsequently poll the x location.

If this can be done, the final solution would account for noise in the system (i.e. each y point polled will be within a given tolerance... thus, the two or more points polled to fit the sine wave would cause additive errors...), but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

Thanks!  I think it's a pretty interesting problem :)  Let me know if you need any further clarification!

-Kadaj

Comment: Is there a DC offset to the signal or is it purely $f(t)=Y \sin (\omega t + \varphi)$ ?

Comment: @ja72, I don't think there's $\omega$ since the frequency is known.

Comment: Ah, good point ja72.  I am looking for a solution in which there can be a DC offset.

Comment: @vadim123, yes, I suppose my notation isn't the best >_<;;  So, in a system in which I did not know $\omega$, I think I would require at least 3 points.  Since I know $\omega$, I believe it can be done in 2, I just cannot seem to arrive at a solution :'(

Comment: @KadajNakamura - frequency is $f=\frac{\omega}{2 \pi}$. So $\omega$ is just frequency in _rad/s_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the general equation $f(t) = Y \sin (\omega t + \varphi)$ where $\omega$ is known and two points, $y_1 = f(t_1)$ and $y_2=f(t_2)$ the solution is

$$ Y = \frac{ \sqrt{ y_1^2 + y_2^2 - 2 y_1 y_2 \cos (\omega(t_2-t_1))}}{| \sin ( \omega(t_2-t_1))|} $$

$$ \varphi = 2\pi - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y_2 \sin \omega t_1 - y_1 \sin \omega t_2}{y_2 \cos \omega t_1 - y_1 \cos \omega t_2} \right) $$

Why?

I expanded the sine function into two components

$$ f(t) = A \sin \omega t + B \cos \omega t $$

where $Y=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and $\tan(\varphi) =  \frac{B}{A}$. The two points are

$$ y_1 = A \sin \omega t_1 + B \cos \omega t_1 $$
$$ y_2 = A \sin \omega t_2 + B \cos \omega t_2 $$

or in matrix form

$$ \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \sin \omega t_1 & \cos \omega t_1 \\ \sin \omega t_2 & \cos \omega t_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} $$

with the inverse

$$\begin{pmatrix} \sin \omega t_1 & \cos \omega t_1 \\ \sin \omega t_2 & \cos \omega t_2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sin( \omega (t_2-t_1))} \begin{pmatrix} \mbox{-}\cos \omega t_2 & \cos \omega t_1 \\ \sin \omega t_2 & \mbox{-}\sin \omega t_1 \end{pmatrix}$$

or

$$ \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sin( \omega (t_2-t_1))} \begin{bmatrix} y_2 \cos \omega t_1 - y_1 \cos \omega t_2 \\ y_1 \sin \omega t_2 - y_2 \sin \omega t_1 \end{bmatrix} $$

So

$$ Y = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} = \sqrt{ \left( \frac{y_2 \cos \omega t_1 - y_1 \cos \omega t_2}{\sin( \omega (t_2-t_1))} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y_1 \sin \omega t_2 - y_2 \sin \omega t_1}{\sin( \omega (t_2-t_1))}  \right)^2 } $$

and

$$ \varphi = n \pi + \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{B}{A} \right) = n \pi + \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y_1 \sin \omega t_2 - y_2 \sin \omega t_1}{y_2 \cos \omega t_1 - y_1 \cos \omega t_2} \right) $$

Comment: This definitely looks promising!  Thank you, @ja72 (especially considering how quickly you replied)!  Have to run now, but will try it out later today/tomorrow =)  Tried to bump it, but I don't have enough rep on here yet T^T

Comment: Oh, I have a quick question -- can you point me in the right direction for this derivation?  Is there a name for this type of problem or field that I can read up on it more?

Comment: I used a 2x2 system to fit the function into the data points. Essentially this is a least squares fit, but with zero error. See edited reply for details.

Comment: Awesome !!  Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the matrix inversion line read to the right of the determinate?  -->

\begin{pmatrix} \cos \omega t_2 & \mbox{-}\cos \omega t_1 \\ \mbox{-}\sin \omega t_2 & \sin \omega t_1 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Final edit:  so, the signs being flipped in the derivation just affect the $\varphi$ result, but it's correct in the original equations in your answer, as far as I can tell.  At any rate, this was a massive help!

Comment: @KadajNakamura - I extracted out the negative of the determinant. This was such as to make the factor positive for $t_2>t_1$. It is ultimately arbitrary as the end result is the same.

Comment: OK -- I see!  Thank you so much, again!

Comment: I had issues with the equation because the denominator can be negative. Even if t2 > t1 it does not prevent it from being negative. Seeing the final equation of Y, I would say that we can safely force the absolute value of the sin as it is sqrt(sine^2).

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina - you are correct. I have added the absolute operator on the denominator of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Nyquist limit, two samples are not enough to have it, considering that your signal is just a period of a sinus, corresponding to a sinc in frequency.

Imaging the two points are just the two zeros of your sinusoidal signal, how can you recover anything from that?

A good question would be how many points are then needed. I guess three, but does not have demonstration.

This is for total recovery of the signal. For just phase, two points are right.

Comment: Welcome to our site!